# Android not broadcasting ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED consistently for bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to get my Android VoIP application to work with bluetooth headsets.

I have set everything up according to the documentation on the Headset profile (get the default bluetooth adapter, query for the headset profile proxy and set up the profile listener). I also set up a BroadcastReceiver to listen for Bluetooth events. When I see that a device has connected (`BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED` is broadcast with state `BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED`), I call `startVoiceRecognition()` on that newly connected device.

Later, when I wish to set up the call, I invoke the AudioManager bluetoothSCO functions:

```
if(shouldTurnBluetoothOn){
   am.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
   am.startBluetoothSco();
}else{
    am.stopBluetoothSco();
    am.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
}
```

I've made sure that my audio modules are initialized to be compatible with bluetooth SCO: That is, my `AudioTrack` is initialized with `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` in 8KHz, and the `AudioRecord` uses `android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` and samples at 8KHz.

---

Now, the problem is that this does not work consistently.

According to Android documentation for `startVoiceRecognition()`:

> Users can listen to ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED. If this function
>   returns true, this intent will be broadcasted with EXTRA_STATE set to
>   STATE_AUDIO_CONNECTING.

I don't consistently see this broadcast, even though the call to startVoiceRecognition() always returns true. When I DO see the broadcast, bluetooth seems to work.

What's the deal? I've run my app on a Nexus 5 with Lollipop as well as an S3 on Android 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Use these actions in your intent filte:

```
BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
```

And add the category    `intentFilter.addCategory(BluetoothHeadset.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT_COMPANY_ID_CATEGORY + "." + BluetoothAssignedNumbers.PLANTRONICS);`